# How to explode single point on Pie Chart + Report Builder 3.0 + SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2012

In both SSD  and Report Builder 3.0 when you click CustomAttributes under DataPoint, Nothing expands out. Its just Gray, theres no way to set the exploded property or specify an expression to do this.

[image]

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I've guessed you are looking for something like this?

[image: Pie chart with data points outside chart]

If so then go to 'General' then 'CustomAttributes', then change the properties 'PieLabelStyle' to 'Outside' you can set the call out line to any colour you wish.  In the screenshot below l have selected 'Black'

[image]

This was done using Report Builder v3.0, l'll try later with SQL Server Data Tools and see if it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear possible unless you install Report Builder 2.0  See [tech net article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/6b530d1c-1cbe-48e7-84ef-a2468c72bbdb/how-to-explode-a-single-point-on-a-pie-chart) Sounds like a bug to me